# Backup file from WIndows to Linux

Tags: powershell, backup, file-watcher

Could anyone suggest some good ways of backing up a file from a Windows machine to a Linux platform using a batch file of powershell command?

My goal is to monitor a file for modification using a powershell script on startup, and then to back it up to the linux machine when modified.

Here is the lovely powershell script written by BigTeddy which I am in the proccess of modifying to execute a transfer script on the 'FileChanged' event:

The original can be found [here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Powershell-FileSystemWatche-dfd7084b)

```
$folder = 'c:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents'
$filter = 'myFileToWatch.csv'

$fsw = New-Object IO.FileSystemWatcher $folder, $filter -Property @{IncludeSubdirectories = $false;NotifyFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]'FileName, LastWrite'}

Register-ObjectEvent $fsw Changed -SourceIdentifier FileChanged -Action {
    <...CODE TO TRANSFER FILE...>
}
```

I have investigated several possibilities:

- rSync as part of Cygwin
- cwRsync
- robocopy

Unfortunatly I have had little success with *Cygwin* as an apparent bug has prevented the 'postinstall' from completing .. (but thats another story)

<strike>I have also run into problems with Windows refusing to recognize the installer for the *Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit Tools* which contains said *Robocopy*.</strike>
It has now decided to play ball.

cwRsync(free) does not support serving files.

I am very new to digging around in the depths of Windows so I imagine there are many possibilities of which I am unaware.

Comment: Try `pscp.exe` or WinSCP's .Net assembly. See this question: [How to use PSCP to copy file from Unix machine to Windows machine where target path has spaces?](http://superuser.com/questions/532919/how-to-use-pscp-to-copy-file-from-unix-machine-to-windows-machine-where-target-p)

Comment: Alternatively, if the Linux server is running Samba you could use `robocopy` to transfer files to a shared folder.

Comment: +beatcracker +Ansgar Wiechers
Thanks for the answers. All good suggestions. I have decided to go with WinSCP's .NET assembly as it is documented in a simple way and will integrate with my script nicely.